# How to migrate JDBC URL based testcontainers to Junit 5

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, testcontainers

I have worked spring boot + testcontainers test based on JUnit 4.

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public Test {
    ...
    public void someTest() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

test properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:mysql:5.6://hostname/db?TC_MY_CNF=mysql
    username: user
    password: pass
```

this test works properly, testcontainers uses JDBC Url string to initiate test container with MySQL 5.6.

Now I wanted to remove junit 4 from the project in favor to use JUnit 5.

Does testcontainers + Spring boot have ability to initiate containers in the similar way (by using JDBC URL) but using JUnit 5?

If yes - how to do it, or which workaround may be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC URL style containers are testing framework agnostic, you can use it with any framework as long as you run it on JVM :)

Comment: yes you are right, my problem was that I excluded junit4 from mysql container maven dependency, `ClassNotFound` is thrown in that case (for `TestRule` class). So it has dependency to junit4. When I removed excluding it works